.NET SQL Deadlocks (randomly) not picked up by SqlCommand
I'm really struggling with something, and I was hoping that I could get some advice or if someone could point me in the right direction with this.
I have a program that processes entries concurrently and there's a lot of SQL Server database activity going on. There are deadlocks that occur and when they throw errors in the code, that is fine, transactions are rolled back and the state of the database is consistent.
I was seeing partially committed data in the database for a handful of entities out of a few thousand that were processed. After numerous investigations and an eventual comparison of SQL Server Profiler results to errors logged, I noticed that some deadlocks were appearing in SQL Server Profiler but not being thrown in the code.
In these scenarios, a SqlCommand is running on a connection that is enlisted in a CommittableTransaction. A deadlock occurs on the call to ExecuteReader() but that isn't thrown as an error in the code, I can only see it in SQL Server Profiler.
What happens next, is that the transaction is rolled back but due to no error being picked up in the code, so the data that was processed until that point is correctly reverted, but the rest of the SQL runs successfully and commits immediately to the database.
The code still thinks it is in a transaction, only when the Commit is called does it then register that the transaction has been aborted. I can't find a way to verify in the code successfully if a connection is still enlisted in a transaction in these scenarios as it looks like an inconsistency between .NET and SQL Server after an undetected deadlock.
Does anyone have experience with this sort of scenario or any advice for me?

Sounds like you should use SET XACT_ABORT ON somewhere in code

Are you invoking SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() in some places without actually reading its contents? Ref: SqlCommand.ExecuteReader Note: If a transaction is deadlocked, an exception may not be thrown until Read is called.

In addition to the comment by @AlwaysLearning, are you using T-SQL TRY/CATCH? See The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions.

Can you show some actual code?

Thank you very much for the comments. The data is always read after calling ExecuteReader() and no try/catch is used in the SQL (it is a one line select). The deadlock is thrown upon reading the data, but I can see in SQL profiler, that everything continues successfully even after the deadlock is reported in profiler. I did find a reported bug on GitHub that looks like it might have something to do with this https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/458

@Charlieface - I can't put enough code in here for an appropriate amount of context but basically it is happening sometimes when there's a high amount of concurrent reads on a specific table and a SqlDataReader reads the data. The only other consistent finding from SQL Profiler is that this happens when the SPID that was deadlocked was first to start reading the data and lost to a SPID that was second to start reading the data. When the first SPID that reads the data wins the deadlock, the deadlocks is then always thrown to the code.

A deadlock or other SqlException during command execution might not be raised by ExecuteReader until the client application retrieves all result sets and errors returned by the query. A gotcha exists with multi-statement batches and stored procedures under the scenarios below because the exception message follows the result set and meta data in the underlying TDS protocol stream:

An error is caught by T-SQL TRY/CATCH while executing a row-returning statement.
An error occurs after a row-returning statement successfully executes.

The example code below will not raise the SqlException unless the NextResult line is uncommented in order to read the second result with the SQL error message.
string sqlBatchText = @"
BEGIN TRY
    SELECT 1/0 AS DivideByZeroError;
 END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH;
";

int rowCount = 0;
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Integrated Security=SSPI"))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlBatchText, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read()) { ++rowCount; };

            //SqlException is not thrown unless all results are consumed
            // while (reader.NextResult()) { }; 
        }
        Console.WriteLine("{0} rows read", rowCount);
    }
}
catch
{
    throw;
}

See The Curious Case of Undetected SQL Exceptions for additional details and explanation of this defensive programming technique.
